# JSON.parse is giving error

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I have written a chunk of code.

```
function getScreenshotObj (pathToFirstFile) {
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) =>{
        console.log("Path to temp dir : " + pathToFirstFile)
        fs.readFile(pathToFirstFile,function(err,fileContents){
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            else{
                screenshotObject = JSON.parse(fileContents)
                obj = {pathToFirstFile : pathToFirstFile , screenshotObject:screenshotObject ,accesstoken : accesstoken}
                return resolve(obj)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

It's giving me an error at JSON.parse(). Uncaught syntax error : Unexpected end of input at JSON.parse().I checked the syntax using online JS syntax and they said code is syntactically valid. Please correct me where I am making mistake.

Comment: Well what *are* the file contents? And is this code running in Node or the browser or something else?

Comment: file contents is path to first file in the dir. Yes ,code is running in node , basically it's for desktop app (using Electron) , so it runs in Chromium

Comment: The `.readFile()` operation returns a *buffer*, not a string, if you don't specify the file encoding as the second argument.

Comment: *"I checked the syntax using online JS syntax"* - All JSON is valid JS syntax, but not all JS is valid JSON syntax. You cannot check JSON validity with a JS syntax checker. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to find of your file is valid JSON.

Comment: it's not working. 
Actually , I came to know that it not reading the file placed in tmp dir of my linux . I console file contents , but it's empty. But, the file is there in the system

Comment: Sounds like the path is wrong. And don't forget to localise those members `screenshotObject` and `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

For `fs.readFile` if you don't specify encoding than raw data buffer is returned.
[source](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback)

Change:

```
fs.readFile(pathToFirstFile, function(err, fileContents) {
```

to

```
fs.readFile(pathToFirstFile, 'utf8', function(err, fileContents) {
```